# How do I force garbage collection for cleared Grid data

Tags: c#, maui

How can I remove Grid data from Process Memory?

I have a MainPage with just a button which navigates to a transient TestPage.
Inside the TestPage, I have a Grid with 100 buttons that do nothing.

When I navigate back to the MainPage from the TestPage, I see a chunk of Process Memory that stays there, even though I've navigated away from TestPage.

[image: Memory Usage]

I've tried:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    NumGrid.Clear();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

But this didn't clear the data from Process Memory.

Also, inside the TestPage, I wrote code to re-create the Grid with 100 buttons on button press.

```
public void Regen_Grid()
{
    NumGrid.Clear();
    GC.Collect();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        NumGrid.Add(new Button { Text = i }, 0, 1);
        NumGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition(GridLength.Auto));
    }
}
```

Every time I re-created the Grid, another chunk of Process Memory is used up.

[image: Regen_Grid bumps]

Eventually the app crashes.

Comment: seems to be a thing in maui: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12039#issue-1492824890 | https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+memory+leak

Comment: @RandRandom - that issue is closed; in its title line it links to [13327](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/13327) that fixes it. In [Maui Release](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/releases), search for `13327`. This is included in `8.0.0-preview.1.7762`. I think one can set Nuget Manager to allow prereleases, then manually download that pre-release. OR wait until a supported release includes `13327`.